# How can i run correctly a complex JMeter scripts with JSR233 that read Excels?

Tags: java, excel, jmeter

I'm developing a Java application that run JMeter scripts and then takes from the report the information used to insert into a database.
The Jmeter script has got a module configuration and JSR233 sampler used to read from external an Excel in order to drive the tests and API invocation.

If i run the script form JMeter GUI i haven't problems but if i run the script from the Java code i got an error during the execution of JSR233 Sampler used to read the excel.

Following my snippet code to invoke JMeter and scripts from Java code:

```
package jmeter;
            
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OpenJMX {

    public static String reportPath;

    public static String getReportPath() {
        return reportPath;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static String RunJmeter(Properties myPropertiesFile) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Jmeter location
            File jmeterHome = new File(System.getProperty("jmeter.home", myPropertiesFile.getProperty("JMETER_PROPERTIES_PATH")));
            String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            
            // Ready to start JMX scenario location
            File testPlan = new File(System.getProperty("testPlan.location", myPropertiesFile.getProperty("SCRIPT_PATH") + myPropertiesFile.getProperty("SCRIPT_NAME")));
            
            if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
                if (testPlan.exists()) {
                    File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");
                    if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                        // JMeter Engine
                        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                        // Initialize Properties, locale, etc.
                        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash +"OracoloCertificate.jks");
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
                        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
                        JMeterUtils.findClassesThatExtend(Sheet.class);
                        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

                        // Set directory for HTML report
                        String repDir = jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "HTMLReport";
                        JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir", repDir);

                        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
                        SaveService.loadProperties();

                        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
                        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(testPlan);

                        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
                        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                        }

                        // Store execution results into a .csv file
                        File logFile = setReportPath(myPropertiesFile.getProperty("REPORT_PATH"), jmeterHome);       
                        
                        //Summiraser summer = null;
                        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector();
                        ReportGenerator reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator(logFile.getPath(), logger); //creating ReportGenerator for creating HTML report
                        logger.setFilename(logFile.getPath());
                        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

                        // Run JMeter Test
                        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                        jmeter.run();

                    }
                }
            }
            String executionId = "OK";
            return executionId;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            String exc = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);       
            System.err.println(exc);
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static File setReportPath(String reportPathProperties, File jmeterHome) {
        try {
            String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm");
            LocalDateTime now = CurrentDateTime.getTimeNow();
            File logFile;
            if(reportPathProperties.isEmpty()) {
                logFile = new File(jmeterHome + slash + "Report " + dtf.format(now) + ".jtl");
            }
            else {
                logFile = new File(reportPathProperties + slash + "Report " + dtf.format(now) + ".jtl");
            }
            reportPath = logFile.getPath();
            return logFile;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            String exc = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);       
            System.err.println(exc);
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

There the code used into JSR233 Sampler to read the excel:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

String foglio = "${foglio}";
String webService = "${webService}";
String testCase = "${testCase}";
String path = "${pathProjectFiles}" + "/DATA INPUTS.xlsx";

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
in.close();
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(foglio);


int nrRows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int nrColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

for (int i = 1; i <= nrRows; i++) {

    if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(testCase)) {

        for (int j = 1; j < nrColumns; j++) {
            vars.put(webService + "_" + sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
        }
        
        break;
    }

}
```

The errore that i got on Java application execution is:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; import org.apache.poi.ss.userm . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: getLastRowNum() on undefined variable or class name: sheet : at Line: 21 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; import org.apache.poi.ss.userm . . . '' : sheet .getLastRowNum ( ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables; import org.apache.poi.ss.userm . . . '' at line number 21
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:231) ~[java.scripting:na]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) ~[ApacheJMeter_java-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

It seems that the Sheet object isn't recognized despite the libraries are improted correctly.

Have you got any idea about this error?

Thanks for supporting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see where you're calling `getLastRowNum()` function so the code you've provided is not relevant for the issue, check your other scripts and make sure you properly declare/instantiate the `sheet` there.

Also be aware that since JMeter 3.1 [you should be using Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) so I would suggest switching the language to `groovy`

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
>
> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So you will need to change `String foglio = "${foglio}";` to `String foglio = vars.get("foglio");` and so on.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, thanks for the answer! The part of code where the function getLastRowNum() is called into JSR233 Sampler - int nrRows = sheet.getLastRowNum(); 
The error that i've got on Java (Eclipse) is that this method is unrecognized despite there are the libraries.